# Spring @Recover and @Retry not working when org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture throws Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I am using Springs kafkaTemplate to publish a message to Kafka topic, Now in order to implement some fail-safe mechanism I want to retry up to some variable amount of tries (in case of Kafka is down or some network failure) and if after "n" no. of retries, The recovery method annotated with `@Recover` should run.

**Here is my Interface definition for the same:**

```
@Retryable(
   value = {PartnerPortalException.class},
   maxAttempts = 2,
   backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100)
)
void sendMessage(BizWebKafkaTopicMessage message) throws PartnerPortalException;

@Recover
void recoverFromSendMessageFailure(PartnerPortalException ex, BizWebKafkaTopicMessage message);
```

Also org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate#send() method returns ListenableFuture where i can have my callbacks (success and failure).

**Implementation of my Interface**

```
@Override
    public void sendMessage(BizWebKafkaTopicMessage message) {
        LOGGER.debug("Publishing Message : {} to Kafka Topic : {} from {}#sendMessage ", message, topicName, CLASS_NAME);

        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, BizWebKafkaTopicMessage>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);

        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Unable to publish message : {} to topic : [{}] due to : {} from {}#sendMessage() ", message, topicName, ex.getMessage(), CLASS_NAME);
                // TODO Implement Retrying publishing of messages to kafka-topic.
                throw new PartnerPortalException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.toString(), ERROR_PUBLISHING_MESSAGE_TO_KAFKA, (Exception) ex);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, BizWebKafkaTopicMessage> sendResult) {
                LOGGER.info("Message : {} published to topic : [{}] with offset = [{}] from {}#sendMessage() ", message, topicName, sendResult.getRecordMetadata().offset(), CLASS_NAME);
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is even when `onFailure()` callback throws the exception, `@Retryable` doesn't work and so does `@Recover`.

I am suspecting this is because nested inner class. Is there a way I can propagate this exception thrown by onFailure() callback to @Retryable annotation.

**Note **: Why onFailure is being triggered, I shut down my zookeeper and Kafka processes running in the background in order to test my @Retryable and @Recover fail-safe mechanism.

Comment: Annotations, generally, belong on the implementation, not the interface. Next you are using multithreading, and the retry mechanism is bound to a single thread, the exception is thrown after the `sendMessage` has been already called finished (I suspect).

Comment: Yes, that's correct, if I use `future.get()` instead of `future.addCallback()` everything works seamlessly.

Comment: Hence it will not work, as the retry interceptor already succesfully finished the method call and cleaned up all retry resources. Not sure if there is an async interceptor thing. But you probably need something, specific for kafka (not sure if the template supports interceptors/aop etc.). Or make all calls blocking.